# Terminology for a function following an exponential growth but being discrete for non-negative integer numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, exponential-function

We currently have a discussion at work about the terminology for a function following this simple exponential law:

$$
y = C^x 
$$

where x is following discrete steps
$$
x \in N _0 (0, 1, 2, ...)
$$

What would be the preferred terminology for this function? Is it still called an exponential function if it is discretized? Or would it be called an exponential series?

Sorry for this very basic question and thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) is probably the term you are looking for. You could say something like

> Let $C$ be a fixed positive integer and let $u_n$ be the geometric sequence defined by $u_n = C^n$ for all $n \geqslant 0$.

Formally, a sequence of integers is a map from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$, so this corresponds exactly to your need of having discrete steps. The sequence $n \to C^n$ is geometric, but the term *geometric sequence* covers the slightly larger class of sequences of the form $n \to ar^n$, where $a$ and $r$ are numbers.

EDIT (answer to the comment). The term *sequence* is sufficiently flexible to allow the case you describe. Just say: let $(u_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ be the geometric sequence defined by $u_n = C^n$ for all $n \geqslant 1$. If $u_0$ is nevertheless defined, but if $u_0 \not= C^0$, you could still say that *the restriction of the sequence to the positive integers is geometric* or that *the subsequence $(u_n)_{n > 0}$ is the geometric sequence $C^n$*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. would you still call it a geometric sequence if N would be limited to positive integer numbers (i.e. starting from 1)? This was the second problem we were facing because of the different behaviour from the starting point.

In case you have an answer to this, would it ok for you if I modify the question and you modify the answer correspondingly?

Comment: It is preferable not to change the question, but I will edit my answer to cover your comment.